# Example of countries restricting companies registered in tax havens?

Tags: taxation

I would like to know which countries do not allow companies with offices registered in tax havens to operate on their territory. And if there are such countries, to what degree their restrictions apply.

Probably the former communist countries had lot of restrictions against tax havens (because they were isolated from the West anyways), although I heard of cases when communists made joint ventures with Western corporations which could very well had offices in tax havens.

Comment: An interesting question, but you will have to define tax haven. I don't think countries have a consensus on that.